# Java Multiplication of static fields?

Tags: java, multiplication

This is probably the most obvious question on stackoverflow. Please Help! What is wrong with this code?

```
public class LevelOne extends Move {
    static int block1x = 3;
    static int block1y = 1;
    static int block2x = 3;
    static int block2y = 2;
    static int block3x = 3;
    static int block3y = 3;
    block1x *= 32;
    block1y *= 32;
    block2x *= 32;
    block2y *= 32;
    block3x *= 32;
    block3y *= 32;
}
```

On line 7 it says it expected { instead of ;
On line 14 it actually says it expected } to complete classbody. Why???

Comment: I was just about to post an answer for your asteroid question right when you deleted it. I spent like 30 minutes on it, if you wanna check it out. Re-post it and put the link here. Don't forget to reference me @peeskillet

Comment: @peeskillet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707114/java-sprite-falling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with doing this:

```
public class LevelOne extends Move {
    static int block1x = 3*32;
    static int block1y = 1*32;
    static int block2x = 3*32;
    static int block2y = 2*32;
    static int block3x = 3*32;
    static int block3y = 3*32;
}
```

The actual values 96, 32, 64, etc. will be computed at compile time. You're probably better off defining a `static final int multipier = 32` constant, so that each of your fields would be defined as `static int block1x = 3 * multiplier` and so on. Your code will be easier to read and more maintainable.

That should be ok because those are `static` fields. For the general case with non-`static` fields, this part should be inside a method or a constructor of your class:

```
block1x *= 32;
block1y *= 32;
block2x *= 32;
block2y *= 32;
block3x *= 32;
block3y *= 32;
```

Right now they are in the class declaration, where we can define fields, methods and constructors (among other things). That space is used to define what the class has. To define specific code, use methods or constructors.

Comment: I am sorry, but the first part of this answer seems to be misleading. There is very little sense in initializing static variables inside a constructor.

Comment: @AndreyChaschev I just rewrote the answer

Answer (score 2):

The initialization part should be in a static section or in a static method:

```
public class LevelOne extends Move {
    static int block1x = 3;
    static int block1y = 1;
    static int block2x = 3;
    static int block2y = 2;
    static int block3x = 3;
    static int block3y = 3;

    // will be called right after the static variables are initialized
    static{
        block1x *= 32;
        block1y *= 32;
        block2x *= 32;
        block2y *= 32;
        block3x *= 32;
        block3y *= 32;
    }
}
```

or you could declare these fields as instance fields (same as above, just remove the `static` word).